# 'rcdd' package in R wont install- Configure: error: GNU MP not found, see README ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rcdd’

Tags: r, r-package

When trying to install the package 'rcdd' which is needed to install the 'betapart' package it comes up with the error:

**Configure: error: GNU MP not found, see README ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rcdd’**

I'm not sure how to fix this issue

**I updated R to the latest version and it now works**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on a Ubuntu machine the following should resolve missing dependencies:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev
```